# JSF/ICEFaces takes very long time in rendering response

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I have a JSF/ICEFaces application that was working fine but all of the sudden it started taking sinfully long time in rendering response phase! I can tell from the console that the java part completes fine but it takes like 10 minutes to display the web page!

I'm using JBoss as my application server.

Could you please tell me how to go about debugging this problem? I don't even know where to start. Please tell me also if putting some code here will help in knowing the root of the problem. To start with, do you think it's a JBoss problem or application problem?

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of [BalusC: Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html)

Is your page particularly complex? For example if you have a large dataTable where each row contains logic then the render phase may take ages.

Comment: Great Link and suggestions! yeah I have datatable with many rows but I also have another page with simple stuff on and still slow. The thing that is confusing me is that it never used to take that long!
Using the link you mentioned: RENDER_RESPONSE 6 phase is taking forever do you know how I can dig deeper?

Comment: The Bean part seems to complete reasonably fast so it's not from there but the part of Rendering JSF response is what seems to be taking long

Comment: See if you can turn up your log4j level for JSF to debug or trace. It will be super noisy but you may get an idea of what is causing the delay.

Comment: Thanks for your comments it led to the problem which was very slow queries

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use tools like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843) to see if there is some Ajax functionality that blocks the render process. IceFaces as I know it relies heavily on doing everything on the serverside of the application and then send the results to the browser for displaying. 
Maybe your use of the components generates a lot of communication to the server or the component can not be updated.

I would look into IceFaces it has proven as unstable and problem prone all the times I worked with it. They have a own forum where you often find an answer to your problems. I think it is on Icefaces.org. But without knowing more I can't really tell where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Janusz. I will check their forums and maybe post there. I noticed though that this is happening when I first start the application so Firebug is not showing anything because it's the first time I load the app!

Comment: This is a very good hint :) The first time you start the application the application need to initialize everything, load all the libraries and classes etc. This can take some time depending on what you are doing. It should not take 10 minutes but this may be the direction to look at. Are you creating a huge amount of application scoped beans? How long does it take to initialize your database connections etc.

Comment: I have no application scope beans, all of my beans are request scope! plus I can tell from the console messages that the it fetches stuff from DB and then closes connection successfully! you are right it always takes longer at the beginning as it initializes everything but never 10-minutes+ as in my case right now! plus it used to takes like 2-3 minutes to start up the application but now suddenly it's taking so long! I can't recall doing any major change (and this is what driving me nut :D)